# CakePHP login fail

Tags: mysql, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, bluehost

I have simple cakephp application, I build using this tutorial [Simple Authentication and Authorization Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html). I have the same exact code block as from the tutorial.

I run this on my computer using Apache/MySQL, it all works fine. When I deploy it to my shared hosting (Bluehost) I start getting login failures.

I checked the MySQL db on my local and the server. Difference is passwords in my local db is hashed but passwords on the hosting dbs are plain. (It is the same exact code running.) (I want to be clear on this point, this is not my intention and obviously a different behavior but I do not know what is the cause of it.)

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(50),
    password VARCHAR(50),
    role VARCHAR(20),
    created DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    modified DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
);
```

These are the relevant methods from my controller for signup and login respectively:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}

public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}
```

and finally this is the beforeSave() method of my model:

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

On my local computer I can first add a user and later login with that user. On the server I can add a user but when I wanted to login I see the error message "Invalid username or password, try again"

Comment: Why aren't you storing the passwords hashed on the server?

Comment: That is what I am asking. My intention is to store them hashed. For some reason they are stored in plain. I do not know what is causing this behavioral difference.

Comment: Seems like the `AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);` call is failing.

Comment: Do you have `Security.salt` set on `Config/core.php`?

Comment: @bfavaretto I set the salt value to some random value. I am using the same core.php file on both locations.

Comment: @Greg if `AuthComponent::password` fails, am I not supposed to see an error message in add?

Comment: if you add `debug($this->data)` and `debug($this->alias)` in the beforeSave() function, do you see them ? And are the printed values correct ? By the way, is your debug level set to more than 0 ?

Comment: I found out the problem. I forgot to upload my model file (User.php). But somehow it still created entries in the db. Obviously it lacked the custom logic for hashing the passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to define the beforeSave function to accept a default parameter. This seems to be an issue between cakephp and php 5.4

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

See here for more info:
http://community.webfaction.com/questions/8397/cakephp-2-auth-failing-on-production-only

Comment: My php version on production is 5.2.17, but I will give it a try and thank you for the link.